# Returning a value based on a lookup

Tags: c#, lookup

I am trying to return a value (`a.tnAddress`) from a custom class based on a lookup (`foreach` loop).  Depending on the type of transaction, I will need to do the `foreach` loop based on different properties (`sExecID`, `iMsgSeqNum, or`sClOrderID`).  I prefer to not have 3 different`foreach` loops just but I am not sure how else to re-write this.

Keep in mind that the code is working fine; I just want to simplify it.

```
private TreeNode GetNodeAddress(cls_Transactions trPassedInTransaction)
{  
    switch (trPassedInTransaction.sMessageType)
    {
        case "Q":
        case "8b":
            foreach (cls_Transactions a in cls_GlobalVariables.transList)
            {
                if (trPassedInTransaction.sExecID == a.sExecID)
                {
                    return a.tnAddress;
                }
            }
            break;
        case "3":
            foreach (cls_Transactions a in cls_GlobalVariables.transList)
            {
                if (trPassedInTransaction.iMsgSeqNum == a.iMsgSeqNum)
                {
                    return a.tnAddress;
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            foreach (cls_Transactions a in cls_GlobalVariables.transList)
            {
                if (trPassedInTransaction.sClOrderID == a.sClOrderID)
                {
                    return a.tnAddress;
                }
            }                    
            break;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Do you think the performance is poor? Your code seems good.

Comment: I just didn't want to replicate the foreach loop 3x.  Plus if I wanted to add messages types in the future, i thought there would be an easier way.

Comment: Switch statements are good here. It could be simplified using LINQ but won't be of much help.

Comment: I would avoid switch statements in favour of polymorphism where possible, and in this case it looks easily possible...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will add the use of [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx) to clean up the code the way you want:

```
private TreeNode GetNodeAddress(cls_Transactions trPassedInTransaction)
{
    //a predicate to pass to the FirstOrDefault method
    Func<cls_Transactions,Boolean> filter = null;
    switch (trPassedInTransaction.sMessageType)
    {

        case "Q":
        case "8b":
                 filter = x => trPassedInTransaction.sExecID == x.sExecID;
            break;
        case "3":
                 filter = x => trPassedInTransaction.iMsgSeqNum == x.iMsgSeqNum;
            break;
        default:
                 filter = x => trPassedInTransaction.sClOrderID == x.sClOrderID;                 
            break;
    }

    cls_Transactions result = cls_GlobalVariables.transList.FirstOrDefault(filter);
    return result != null ? result.tnAddress : null;
}
```

As an explanation, the switch statement has just been converted to use a predicate, which is a function type where it passes one parameter (in this case a cls_Transactions) and returns true/false.

The `FirstOrDefault` method is shorthand for the foreach loop and return, foreach-ing through the elements and using the predicate to determine if it meets the required condition, if none meet the required condition it will return a default value (in the case null).

You can use the `First` method also, which will throw an exception if nothing is found :)

Comment: Ok....I think I will have to study my LINQ before I implement this, but Thank You.

Comment: Func<cls_Transactions,Boolean> filter = null; --> in case of Q it will throw an ArgumentNullException so change null to: () => true

Comment: In case of 'Q' (as there is no 'break;') it will fall through to '8b' and use it's filter. There should be no condition here that filter is null, as there is a default on the switch statement.

Comment: @m.t.bennett: I think you should change `Func<cls_Transactions,Boolean> filter = null;` to `Func<cls_Transactions,Boolean> filter;` .  This makes it more obvious that `filter` can never be null.  The C# compiler does not allow possibly unassigned variables to be used, but in this case `filter` is always assigned.  When I see you assign `filter` to `null`, my first inclination is to wonder if there is a code path where that value is used (because otherwise, why assign it at all?).

Comment: @Brian I look at this the other way - if I know the original variable is null (Filter) then I immediately know it needs to be handled at a later date. I think in this situation specifically we know the switch statement is the control path that assigns the variable, and any new code must adhere to this.

Comment: @m.t.bennett : If you don't assign the variable at all, the compiler will **enforce** that it needs to be handled at a later date.  Any new code which introduces new switch elements will fail to compile unless those elements assign filter (since filter must be definitively assigned before it can be used).

Answer (score 2):

I like using a dictionary because to me it looks like tighter cleaner code and you can easily add to the dictionary or if you want later pull the logic from another source and put into the dictionary.

```
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Predicate<cls_Transactions>>();
        dictionary.Add("Q", x => x.sExecID == trPassedInTransaction.sExecID);
        dictionary.Add("8b", x => x.sExecID == trPassedInTransaction.sExecID);
        dictionary.Add("3", x => x.iMsgSeqNum == trPassedInTransaction.iMsgSeqNum);
        dictionary.Add("default", x => x.sClOrderID == trPassedInTransaction.sClOrderID);

        var switchValue = dictionary[trPassedInTransaction.sMessageType] != null
                              ? trPassedInTransaction.sMessageType
                              : "default";
        var result = cls_GlobalVariables.transList.FirstOrDefault(t => dictionary[switchValue](t));
        return result != null ? result.tnAddress : null;
```